# how handle sys.argv if null argument is given

Tags: python, arguments

I've this issue with this condition using sys.argv inside a script.

The script includes several functions to classify, build and transform a dataset, no big deal.

In the beginning of the script I assign external arguments to 2 or 3 variables depending on the arguments.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    nfcv=sys.argv[1]
    pgrid = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].split(",")]
    refit =  sys.argv[3]
else:
    nfcv=sys.argv[1]
    pgrid = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].split(",")]
    refit =  ""
```

Below the command line to run the script with all 3 arg's.

```
OC_run_eval_ML.py 5 "2,4,6,8,10,12,14" y
```

During script execution I want to fit my classifier below only if the 3 argument = "y", if empty then pass

Below what I did

```
def fit(X,y):
    clf.fit(X, y)

if refit == "y" :
    fit(X_train_std,y_train)
else: pass
```

Without the 3rd argument (which mean I don't want to "fit" my model)

```
OC_run_eval_ML.py 5 "2,4,6,8,10,12,14"
```

I get the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OC_run_eval_ML.py", line 25, in <module>
    refit =  sys.argv[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It seems is not accepting the condition : "len(sys.argv) > 2:"

Help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Rgds

Comment: Simple: `len(sys.argv) > 3`, not `> 2`. The list has **four** elements, the script name and 3 argument values.

Comment: Or use `argparse` and let it do the heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys.argv` list always contains the script name as the first argument, so when you have 3 command-line arguments, the length of `sys.argv` will be *4* elements. `len(sys.argv) > 2` is true if there are only 3 elements too.

Test for 3 or more:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    nfcv=sys.argv[1]
    pgrid = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].split(",")]
    refit =  sys.argv[3]
else:
    nfcv=sys.argv[1]
    pgrid = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].split(",")]
    refit =  ""
```

You can simplify this to:

```
nfcv = sys.argv[1]
pgrid = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].split(",")]
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    refit =  sys.argv[3]
else:
    refit =  ""
```

Personally, I'd use the [`argparse` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to do this work for you, or (for more complex projects) with [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/).

Argparse example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Classify, build and transform a dataset')
parser.add_argument("nfcv", help="The NFCV argument...")
parser.add_argument("pgrid", 
    help="Comma-separated pgrid values",
    type=lambda v: [int(x) for x in v.split(",")]
)
parser.add_argument("refit", nargs="?", default="", help="The refit argument...")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

then use `args.nfcv`, `args.pgrid` and `args.refit` in your code.

Demo:

```sh
$ cat demo.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Classify, build and transform a dataset')
parser.add_argument("nfcv", help="The NFCV argument...")
parser.add_argument("pgrid",
    help="Comma-separated pgrid values",
    type=lambda v: [int(x) for x in v.split(",")]
)
parser.add_argument("refit", nargs="?", default="", help="The refit argument...")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(f"NFCV:  {args.nfcv!r}")
print(f"prid:  {args.pgrid!r}")
print(f"refit: {args.refit!r}")

$ python3 demo.py --help
usage: demo.py [-h] nfcv pgrid [refit]

Classify, build and transform a dataset

positional arguments:
  nfcv        The NFCV argument...
  pgrid       Comma-separated pgrid values
  refit       The refit argument...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
$ python3 demo.py foo 42,81,117
NFCV:  'foo'
prid:  [42, 81, 117]
refit: ''
$ python3 demo.py foo 42,81,117 y
NFCV:  'foo'
prid:  [42, 81, 117]
refit: 'y'
```

Note that if `refit` is meant to be a *switch*, then just use a `store_true` action and make it a `-r/--refit` command line argument:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-r', '--refit', action='store_true', default=False,
    help="Enable refit"
)
```

instead of the `parser.add_argument('refit', ...)` line. In that case `args.refit` is a boolean that defaults to `False` and is `-r` or `--refit` is used on the command line is set to `True`. Then just use `if args.refit:` to test for it.

The demo with that change then looks like this:

```sh
$ python3 demo.py --help
usage: demo.py [-h] [-r] nfcv pgrid

Classify, build and transform a dataset

positional arguments:
  nfcv         The NFCV argument...
  pgrid        Comma-separated pgrid values

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -r, --refit  Enable refit
$ python3 demo.py foo 42,81,117
NFCV:  'foo'
prid:  [42, 81, 117]
refit: False
$ python3 demo.py foo 42,81,117 --refit
NFCV:  'foo'
prid:  [42, 81, 117]
refit: True
```

Comment: Using argparse would be great, unfortunately I get an error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OC_run_eval_ML.py", line 96, in <module>
    GridSearchCV(pgrid,5)
NameError: name 'pgrid' is not defined. It seems is not accepting variable args.pgrid from argparse

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho: That's why I tell you to use `args.pgrid`. You can always assign back to `pgrid` with `pgrid = args.pgrid`, but that just clutters your namespace some more.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho: In other words: `parser.parse_args()` returns a new object, whose attributes are the values created from the command-line arguments following the rules configured by using `add_argument()`. It will never create new variables in your own code, that'd be very surprising, and in Python functions you can't create new local names dynamically anyway.

Comment: @Martjin: But I did use args.pgrid. (e.g. I set in my fit function the condition using :  ` if args.refit == "y" :
    fit(X_train_std,y_train) `but I got the error message : aceback (most recent call last):
  File "OC_run_eval_ML.py", line 100, in <module>
    if args.refit == "y" :```
NameError: name 'args' is not defined. Sorry I don't get yet how format text code inside comment window.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho: I don't know how your code is structured; how did you make sure the same code could access `refit` before? Did you pass in `refit` as a function argument, for example? You now need to pass `args` around the same way.

Answer (score 1):

- `argv[0]` is always the name of the program;
- `argv[1]` is the first argument;
- `argv[2]` is the second argument;
  etc.

So if you want to confirm how many arguments there are, you need to remember that the "first" argument is actually the name of the program!

You want `len(sys.argv)>3`, not `2`

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.